# Prove by contradiction that $(n+1)^3 \not= n^3 +(n-1)^3$ for $3$ consecutive positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Prove by contradiction that if $n-1$, $n$, $n+1$ are consecutive positive integers, then the cube of the largest cannot be equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

Assume that:
$$ (n+1)^3 = (n-1)^3+n^3 $$
$$n^3+3n^2+3n+1=n^3-3n^2+3n-1+n^3$$
$$3n^2+1=-3n^2-1+n^3$$
$$n^3-6n^2-2=0$$

I don't know how to move from here. Instead of this solution considered that two of the integers are either odd or even but this idea didn't help much.

Comment: Because FLT lol. :)

Answer (score 5):

$n^3-6n^2-2=0 \implies n^2(n-6)=2$

- $n<6 \implies n^2(n-6)<0$
- $n=6 \implies n^2(n-6)=0$
- $n>6 \implies n^2(n-6)\geq49$

Therefore, $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}:n^2(n-6)\neq2$

Answer (score 4):

Now, you just have to show that the cubic $x^3-6x^2-2 = 0$ has no positive integer roots.

By the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the only possible rational roots are $x = \pm 1, \pm 2$. Hence, the only possible positive integer roots are $x = 1,2$. Is $x = 1$ or $x = 2$ a root? If not, then there are no positive integer solutions $x = n$ to $x^3-6x^2-2 = 0$.

Alternatively, you can use [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem), but that is overkill.

Comment: Why can't the roots be $\pm 1$?

Comment: ^Thanks for that catch.

Comment: Thanks for the Fermat, I have been dying to use that one.

Comment: Nitpicking, but we didn't need to check $n=1$ since $n-1$ is not a positive integer then.

Comment: Lol I was thinking of posting 'because FLT lol' as a comment. :) never mind doing it anyway haha.

Answer (score 3):

This is a big cheating

But $(n+1)^3 = n^3+(n-1)^3$ is in contradiction with [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLastTheorem.html)

Comment: I can't believe this is getting up votes (even if it is technically correct). Using FLT here is like using a strategic thermonuclear device to kill a fly. I assumed that all the FLT comments were jokes,  and not serious answers. :)

Comment: @Deepak: I think that (especially on a homework question) people occasionally find humor in pulling out the most inappropriately powerful tool to solve it.  I suspect the up-votes are being awarded on that account.  It's not exactly responsible, but I don't think anyone will be misled in this instance.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks Brian. Which is why jokesy answers should be left as comments at most IMHO. Anyway, point taken.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $f(x)=x^3-6x^2-2$ has a zero occurring at a non-integer value.

Comment: I would not consider this as a mathematical proof, since it requires drawing a graph and looking at it. Saying for example that $f(1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$ is a valid proof.

Comment: I completely agree. I'm still very new at this so my apologies.